# Confused about how to pass data to another page using getx

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

I am fallowing a video tutorial about getx .I have done completely same thing .But When I try to get data from onether page .Data always  null.What is wrong here

```
    child: TextButton(
        onPressed: () {
          Get.to(
            Pro(),
            transition: Transition.rightToLeftWithFade,

            arguments: 'somethng'
          );
        },
        child: Text("to pro gape")),
```

This is profile page

```
          var data=Get.arguments;     
          : Column(
      children: [
        TextButton(
            child: Text("Move Back"),
            onPressed: () {
           //   Get.back();
            }),
        Text(data),
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this

```
 Get.to(
            Pro(),
            transition: Transition.rightToLeftWithFade,
            arguments:{'something':'something'}
          );
```

Now on next page

```
  var arguments = Get.arguments as Map<String, dynamic>;
    data = arguments['something'] as String;
```

Comment: Now I am getting this error   type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>' in type cast

Answer (score 0):

You can pass data to another page like this.

```
String data = 'something';
Get.to(Pro(),
        transition: Transition.rightToLeftWithFade,arguments:[data]);
```

and for getting data on second page

```
var args = Get.arguments; // this should be placed before build method


var data = args[0]; // this should be placed after build method
```